# What's an example of an unaccelerated particle that's not free?

Tags: forces, reference-frames, relativity

I'm reading Core Principles of Special and General Relativity by James Luscombe. Currently the following section:

> *What's a free particle?* The answer is seemingly self-evident: If free particles are unaccelerated, then not-free particles are accelerated, right? Not so fast. Such reasoning doesn't take into account how acceleration is measured. **Not all unaccelerated particles are free, and not all free particles are unaccelerated**: It depends on the reference frame. *In IRFs, acceleration is caused solely by forces.* No force, no acceleration, and ***forces arise from physical interactions**.*
>
> In noninertial reference frames, acceleration can be an artifact of the choice of frame and not necessarily the result of forces. **Forces can be identified from their physical *sources*.**

I have a few doubts:

1. So a free particle is one that's not accelerated when there are no net forces on it. Does this definition require us to specify a reference frame? ("Net forces" as measured in what frame?)
2. What would be an example of an unaccelerated particle that is **not** free? I mean, if forces are measured w.r.t. a frame, and acceleration is also measure w.r.t. the same frame, then surely a free particle (no net force in that RF) should have no acceleration?

   I can understand how a free particle can be accelerated - if its acceleration is only due to pseudo-forces applicable to that frame and nothing else. In such a case, we know that the net force is zero (as measured internally in that ref. frame. Pseudo-force is external to the RF) - hence free.
3. And what's the difference between the two lines: *"forces arise from physical interactions"*, and *"forces can be identified from their physical sources"*?

Would really appreciate any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free particle is a particle on which no forces act.

A particle will not accelerate in the IRF if the sum of all forces acting on the particle is $0$.

A particle that is acted upon by forces that cancel each other out will not be free, but it will not be accelerating in IRF.

A particle on which no forces act may still be accelerating in a non-IRF.

The difference between "forces arise from physical interactions", and "forces can be identified from their physical sources" is that the first stresses more the fact that with no physical interaction there are no forces, while the other stresses the fact that to prove existence of a force you need to show a physical source. They mean basically the same thing, they just put accents differently.

Comment: Just to clarify: is a free particle one on which **the net force is zero**, or one on which **no forces act at all, regardless of whether or not their resultant is zero**?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Net forces being zero is not enough; For a particle to be called free, there may to be no forces acting on it at all. Net force being $0$ is only enough for the particle to have no acceleration in IRF.

Answer (score 1):

What is a free particle in your frame is not a free particle in a frame that is accelerating with respect to you. Whenever we are talking about forces and motion, we always define a reference frame first.

A particle with zero net force force in a particular frame is a free particle in that frame.

> And what's the difference between the two lines: "forces arise from physical interactions", and "forces can be identified from their physical sources"?

If we take the statements at face value, one states that what is referred to as force is something that arises out of interactions (and not an artefact of the reference frame) and the other states that if we look for signs of where the force is coming from we will be able to distinguish between force and non inertial reference frame effects.

Comment: Thanks! Could you clarify the 2nd and 3rd questions in my post as well? They're related and would help out my understanding.

Comment: So then: example of a non-free, non-accelerated particle would be if there's a pseudoforce acting on it in one direction, which is an artifact of the noninertial frame, and also there's an actual force native to that frame acting in the opposite direction? In such a case, the net force **in that particular frame** is non-zero, but still the acceleration is zero. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yeah. Sounds right.