# Is a free particle one on which there's no NET force or one on which there's no force at all?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm getting different definitions from different sources. Some claim that free particles have no forces acting on them at all (i.e. even if a particle has forces acting on it such that they cancel, it's not free). Other sources explicitly state that there is no net force (like [this](https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Free_particle.html)). Other sources, when I google about this, state that free particles are "free from external influence" - which is kind of vague and can be interpreted either way.

Can someone resolve the confusion?

Comment: *no forces acting on them at all, regardless of whether or not they cancel* If there are no forces, there is nothing to cancel, so I don’t understand your “regardless...” clause.

Comment: @G.Smith: Thanks for pointing that out! Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forces often come from force fields like gravitational or electromagnetic. These differ in different parts of space, so they may cancel in one point but not in another.

Now, suppose a particle is at a point where all forces cancel (and there's a non-empty set of forces being in superposition). Let's now perturb its position. In general, the forces now won't cancel, and the particle will experience acceleration. Suppose that the forces are all directed into the initial point where no net force acted on the particle. Then this initial point would be the point of [stable equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium#Stability). Now, if the particle has too small kinetic energy, it will be bound in the potential well, unable to escape it.

I think it's fair to say that in the case described above a particle, even at the point of equilibrium, where all forces cancel, is not free (it can't escape arbitrarily far given arbitrarily long time). So, I think the case where there's no *net* force, but the set of forces is non-empty shouldn't be included in the definition of a free particle.

Comment: So here's what I've understood: a particle is "free" which, **when viewed from an inertial reference frame**, has no net force acting on it. Is it possible for an observer in a **non-inertial frame** to reliably determine if a particle is free? For example if I'm in a non-IRF and I have an accelerometer, its reading will give me my proper acceleration $a$. I can measure the acceleration of that particle - if it's $-a$, then I can say the acceleration of that particle is an artifact of my own frame's proper acceleration. In that case I can call the particle free- am I correct in this?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari well, once you've subtracted your accelerometer's measurement from the particle's acceleration, you have mathematically switched to an inertial frame. After that you apply a definition of freedom which is contrary to my answer. In particular, the particle could be trapped in a potential well, slowly crossing the point of equilibrium at the moment of observation, and you, with your definition, would still call it free.

Comment: Ah, but then wouldn't that make it impossible for me to determine whether that particle is free or not, if I'm a distant observer in a non-IRF looking at the particle? I mean, in that case, the only way to find out if the particle is free or not is to slightly displace it and see if that introduces a net non-zero force on it. Is that correct? And by the same token, even if I am in an IRF, I'd still need to displace that particle just a bit and observe.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari actually, I think there's no way in general to find out whether a particle is free, even for an inertial observer. The concept of free particle is directly related to the ability of the particle to escape to infinity, which generally can't happen in finite time.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer assumes we are dealing with an inertial frame of reference.

It really depends on what is meant by a "free" particle. The dictionary definition of "free" as an adjective is "not under the control or in the power of another". If a particle is not subjected to a *net force* then what we do know is that the particle either remains at rest or in uniform linear motion according to Newton's first and second law. That doesn't mean the particle is not subjected to any forces. Just that it's not subjected to a net force. Per the definition of "free" the particle is not under the control of the forces.

A dictionary definition of "influence" is "the capacity to have an effect on the character, development, or behavior of someone or something". So here again, if there are forces acting on a particle but they do not affect the character of the particle, then by this definition those forces are not influencing the particle. That can only be the case where the net force of those external forces is zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks! So for a bit of context, it's a follow-up to one of the answer to my previous question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/531677/whats-an-example-of-an-unaccelerated-particle-thats-not-free

If I'm looking for an example of an unaccelerated particle that is not free, then if I define a free particle as one with NO forces on it at all, then it's trivial - just pick anything with net force zero and it won't be free. But if the definition of free particle is that there is no net force, then I'd have to come up with a different example.

Comment: Continuing from previous comment, the accepted answer claims that there can be no force at all and I wanted to be doubly sure.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari See my edit adding the definition of "free". Clearly if the net force is zero the particle is not "under the control" of the forces applied.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Wait a minute. The accepted answer is talking about a non inertial frame. You made no mention of that in this post. Newton's laws apply to inertial frames, not non-inertial frames where pseudo, or fictional forces exist. You really need to be more complete in your question.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari I have edited my answer to indicate I am referring to inertial frames.

Comment: I see. So I'm reading a book in which an IRF is **defined** as a frame in which free particles are unaccelerated. The definition of IRF depends on free particles that way. Basically I'm trying to answer these 2 questions: what is an IRF? What is a free particle? Without running into circular definitions, how can I go about it? Since the book defined IRF in terms of free particle, I assumed it must be possible to define a free particle irrespective of reference frame

Comment: @ShirishKulhari An inertial reference frame is simply one that is not accelerating. That is, a frame in uniform rectilinear motion.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dense, but how do you know if a frame is accelerating or not? I guess that should remove all the confusion. Would you take a particle and if it's accelerating without any sources of force native to that reference frame, you'd conclude that the particle is accelerating due to a pseudo force, and hence the frame is accelerating? Is that it?

Also, how do you define a free particle in the context of a non-inertial frame?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari In an accelerating, or non-inertial, frame pseudo forces are used to explain the observation of apparent forces when in fact one is observing the effects of inertia. For example, if you are driving your car around a corner at high speed you may see an object on the seat next to you sliding away from you toward the other door. It appears to you that a force is pushing the object away from you. But there is no actual force pushing the object. The observation is explained by a pseudo force (the centrifugal force).

Comment: An inertial observer (an observer standing on the street) sees the object attempting to move in a straight line tangent to your circular motion, due to its inertia and Newton's first law (an object at rest or in uniform linear motion will remain so unless acted upon by a net external force). The only real force is the centripetal force trying to keep object in circular motion along with the driver. In this case it’s the friction force between the object and the seat.  I'm afraid that's all I have time for.

Comment: So here's what I've understood: a particle is "free" which, **when viewed from an inertial reference frame**, has no net force acting on it. Is it possible for an observer in a **non-inertial frame** to reliably determine if a particle is free? For example if I'm in a non-IRF and I have an accelerometer, its reading will give me my proper acceleration $a$. I can measure the acceleration of that particle - if it's $-a$, then I can say the acceleration of that particle is an artifact of my own frame's proper acceleration. In that case I can call the particle free- am I correct in this?